# How can I extract list of Types from ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework. I create Entity Model. I want to get all types of instances from DbContext in runtime.

```
public class MyClass
{
   WdmEntities _context =  = new WdmEntities();
   ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
   EntityContainer container = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
   //even if c=>c.FullName
   List<string> nameTypes = container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>().Select(c=>c.Name).ToList();
   List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

   foreach(var name in nameTypes)
   {
    //.GetType return null
    types.Add(Type.GetType(name));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MyContext _context = new MyContext();
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
var nameTypes = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

foreach (var entityType in nameTypes)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(entityType.FullName + "," + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
    types.Add(type);
}
```

By using the `GetItems<EntityType>` method you directly load all your entities from the `ObjectContext.` The parameter that you pass to this method specifies where you want to look for entities. You should use the `OSpace` value to request entity types from the object model. This will map to CLR types except when those types are nested. In that case, you get a composed name with all the outer types in it.

`Type.GetType` expects both the full name of the object and the full name of the assembly. In this example, I use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`. If your entities are defined in another assembly you need to change this.

Comment: ElementType has a FullName but not equal full name of type in assemble. It's problem. Example ElementType = "WdmModel.display_type", but really i have a class display_type in EditorX.EntityModel namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
MyContext _context = new MyContext();
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
var nameTypes = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace).Select(c => c.FullName).ToList();
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

foreach (var name in nameTypes)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(name);
    types.Add(type);
}
```